# Load specific data from text and put into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, text, datagridview, load

I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to create a small program that will help me finish many things.

How it's looks like?

This is how the text file's data is formatted:

```
**;======================= Start**

 (item  (name 256)      (Index 1)   (Image "Wea001")    (Action 1 1) (class
 weapon sword)  (code 1 1 1 1)  (country 2) (level 1)   (wear
 1)                                 (limit Knight 1)    (range 16)  (buy 4) (sell 1)    (endurance
 4)             (specialty  (aspeed 700)                        (Attack 3 10)                   (hit 15)                                                                                                    )                               )

**;======================== end**
```

I need to import the (number beside the name), the (number beside the index), and the (name beside the Image).

User will be loading the text file from an open file dialog and the 3 columns will display the 3 fields that I am asking for help with.

Can anybody show me example of code to **load text file** data, into a **datagridview**? I am using **vb.net**

Comment: **name 256** .. means text size = 256 .. how about **Attack 3 10** ?

Comment: If you have control over how the file is formatted, I strongly suggest you devise a better format as that one could be very challenging to parse.  Perhaps a CSV format, or JSON (it looks a little bit like a poor man's version of JSON, but I'm not familiar enough with JSON to say that with 100% certainty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that uses the existing format.  This uses a datatable to contain the data then it's used as the datasource for the datagridview It searches for the correct line, then splits the line by the closing parenthesis `)`, then extracts the data by splitting each piece by the space.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sr As New StreamReader("InitItem.txt")
        Dim DataString As String = ""
        Dim ImageIndex As Integer = 2
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Index"), New DataColumn("Image")})
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            DataString = sr.ReadLine
            If DataString.Contains("(item") Then
                Dim ParseData() As String = DataString.Split(")"c)
                If (ParseData(ImageIndex).Contains("desc")) Then
                    ImageIndex = 3
                End If
                AddNewRow(ParseData, ImageIndex)
            End If
        End While
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddNewRow(ParseData() As String, ImageIndex As Integer)
        Dim TempRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        TempRow.ItemArray = {ParseData(0).Trim.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1), _
                             ParseData(1).Trim.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1), _
                             ParseData(ImageIndex).Trim.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).Trim(""""c)}
        dt.Rows.Add(TempRow)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Splitting by the `)` ensures that when we want to extract the data after we split by the space, that the string doesn't have the `)` tacked on to the end.

Because the text file format is kind of all over the place I made this code specifically for the data you requested.  If you want something more generic then, as already mentioned, you should consider a more standard format for the file.  Since there doesn't seem to be a lot of data, I would suggest a field/value pair on each line.

Comment: First of all i would like to say too much thanks for this great and fast answers and codes.
2nd i try this code but i got clean datagrid view :(
could you please tell me why there is no data ?!
3rd i accept any edit or special idea from you or any one else that's help but with only text extension
thanks so much again for help and for edit my first post from administrators

Comment: Did you add the columns?  Is the format of the text file exactly like you've shown?  Set a break point at `dt.Rows.Add(TempRow)` and see what data is in TempRow and what data is in ParseData.  You may need to try different indexes in the TempRow.ItemArray statement to get the right data.  My code was tested with the sample you've shown.  If there is any difference in the actual format you'll have to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: hi, this is a copy of the data file that you asking for it's text file and contain all data that i try to create program for it u can download it from here http://www.mediafire.com/?b93qewbc5cikh7b

Comment: I modified my code.  The reason you weren't getting any data is the format of the text file isn't exactly the same as your sample.  I fixed that and also I noted something else, your text file changes it's format part way through.  It goes from name,index,image,desc to name,index,desc,image.  I added code to allow for this so that you get the image in the third column on every row.

Comment: thanks a lot for the new code its working fine and show data now and yes because each line mean 1 item and each item have special image and special details thats why not all items same
i have small thing image must show as image so can we give the program direction to load the image not the image name in the image column ?!
for example we add 1 button when user click on it message show up please select the image direction to load them and he select file call Ex."A" when he select this file program replace the image column
with the image from the direction ?!
thanks a lot your very kind

Comment: are the images in the same folder? Or are you using an imagelist to store the images?  do they all have the same extension?  In the control toolbox is a OpenFileDialog that you can customize for what you need.

Comment: all the image with one folder for example C:\data\image\ and yes all image with same extension *.bmp all we need to give the program the image direction to replace image name with image and this is what i done with your great code tell now
http://www.mediafire.com/?n021kr8kzc1skj3 and this files will help you a lot it' same idea that we are looking for i add all needed files inside this link (software-image-text) download this
http://www.mediafire.com/?ecw4sxmms5s9gcb thanks kind man